# How to build Custom Record Detail Page using lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, detail-page

I have a requirement to hide two fields on campaign object to everyone except for the owner.

I'm trying to use aura:if in lightning component

How can I actually display fields of that specific record. can we override detail page with our lightning component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lightning:recordViewForm` which displays one or more fields, provided by `lightning:outputField`.

> A lightning:recordViewForm component is a wrapper component that accepts a record ID and is used to display one or more fields and labels associated with that record using lightning:outputField. lightning:recordViewForm requires a record ID to display the fields on the record. It doesn't require additional Apex controllers or Lightning Data Service to display record data. This component also takes care of field-level security and sharing for you, so users see only the data they have access to.

Here is an example from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordViewForm/documentation)

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageType">
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Campaign">
        <div class="slds-box">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="OtherField__c" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working