# Custom record detail lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

there is a way to create a custom component similar to the standard component of record detail (with the possibility of clicking on the pencil to modify the entire page)??[image]

Comment: This question has been previously asked, although it was closed by moderators. There is an answer that will point you in the right direction. [Here's the question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224624/how-to-build-custom-record-detail-page-using-lightning-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lightning:recordForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation) here.

With this component, you can view and edit the record by using the `mode="view"` and passing the record id.

> **Viewing a Record with Option to Edit Fields**
>
> Use `mode="view"` and pass the ID of the record and the corresponding object API name to be displayed.

Take a look at the documentation for further details on implementation/examples.

Comment: thank you very much